# What files are required and how to restore a backup in Duplicity

Tags: 16.04, external-hdd, restore, duplicity

I am unable to access a backup made using "backups" after a fresh install of 16.04.  My HDD may be corrupted since the utility replies with "no backups to restore".  Files on the HDD are labeled duplicity-full.20170323T163119Z.vol3.difftar.gz and duplicity-full-signatures.20161221T021439Z.sigtar.gz for example.  The total volume size is 940 MB so there appears to be data there.   I have created a backuplist.txt that shows thousands of file names, but am unable to restore any files using the terminal and numerous approaches.

I have read dozens of articles with many solutions but to no avail. My skill level is not high, so if you have a suggestion please provide specific directions!